# Eclipse Juno: Market Place and Install new Software not working

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-juno, eclipse-marketplace

I want to install svn in Eclipse Juno but I found several things..

1. I have no access to Market Place and a popup shows me that error:

Unexpected exception java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

2. I tried to update the marketplace from this link: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno

But another error was presented.

What I should do to solve this problems? I need help and svn in my eclipse!

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory for more details of the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any firewall? I suspect you need to setup some proxy in order to bypass.
How did you get your eclipse installation, just simple download or you got already ready for you?

Answer (score 0):

It was a proxy problem.

I had to visit Preferences > Network connections and set all the connections to manual with the proxy IP.

Thank you for your help!